# Combination find value of n

Tags: permutations, combinations

$ C_{3}^{n} = 2C_{2}^{n-1}$

Then find the value of n ?
This is combination problem.
How can we find n ? Anyone can explain step by step

Comment: n=C2/(2C2-C3)...

Comment: You should include something about what you've done yourself to solve it. A hint: think of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Kenny Lau added answer for that.. its correct. but want to clarify with steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_{3}^{n} = 2*C_{2}^{n-1}$

$ \frac {n!} {3! (n-3)!}=2 \frac {(n-1)!}{2! (n-3)!}$

$ \frac {n(n-1)(n-2)} {3!}=  {(n-1)(n-2)} $

$  {n(n-1)(n-2)} = 6 {(n-1)(n-2)} $

$  (n-6)(n-1)(n-2) =0$

As n need to be > 3 then n=6

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
C^n_3 &=& 2 C^{n-1}_2 \\
\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6 &=& (n-1)(n-2) \\
n(n-1)(n-2) &=& 6(n-1)(n-2) \\
(n-6)(n-1)(n-2) &=& 0 \\
\end{array}$$
$n=1$ (rejected) or $n=2$ (rejected) or $n=6$.

Comment: When i apply 6 to n its balance both side.. n=6.. Thank you very much kenny Lau.. :) .But i want to clear how to write 1st step. Sorry im beginner for maths.

Comment: @chamaraherath do you know the definition of $C$?

Comment: I have no idea.. 
n!/r!(n-r)! 
is it ?